# I keep receiving the error "type object argument after * must be an iterable, not Skull" while trying to make a text file readable as a map

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, iterable

Working on a tile-based game on pygame. I am trying to read a text file as the map however, I keep getting a Type error that I do not know how to fix

```
    for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map_data):
        for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
            if tile == "1":
                 np = Skull(col, row)
                 SKULL_LIST.append(np)

    for skl in SKULL_LIST:
        s = Skull(*skl)
        self.all_sprites.add(s)
        self.skulls.add(s)
```

Error message I am receiving:

> type object argument after * must be an iterable, not Skull

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line `s = Skull(*skl)` with the line `s = skl`. The meaning of Skull(*skl) is Skull(skl[0], skl[1], ...) which is only defined for mappings (such as lists). Perhaps skl is not a mapping (and in special, not a list)? If you're coming from C or C++, note that pointer dereferencing is implicit in Python, so you need not prefix variable names with an asterisk or an ampersand.